# Expand envvar in minibuffer

Tags: emacs, cygwin, minibuffer

When the cursor is in minibuffer typing `$` and then a few characters, say `$HO` offers envar name completion, for example running cygwin Emacs on Windows 7 it offers me `$HOME`, `$HOMEDRIVE` and `$HOMEPATH`. As well, typing a `/` after a complete variable name such as `$HOME/` and tab shows files in that directory.

Is there a way to expand this variable? So that for example, I can delete part the expanded text and continue?

I am using `iswitchb` but I see the same behavior with `emacs -q` as well.

I am using cygwin build of Emacs 24.3.1 on Windows 7

Comment: What does "expand" mean here?

Comment: @phils I mean replace entered text with `substitute-in-file-name` would transform it to

Comment: Thanks, there seemed to be some confusion between "expand" and "complete", but I understand why now. I can confirm that the expected behaviour (environment variable expansion of `$HOME/` upon `TAB`) occurs in NTEmacs 24.3.1 and also in my old Cygwin Emacs 23.3.1, but not in 24.3.1 under Linux, so something does appear to have changed here.

Comment: Thanks @phils. I can confirm it does not expand (in the sense of replacing) on my MacBook 24.3.1 either. BTW thanks for the question, I realized the difference between expand-file-name and substitute-in-file-name.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have chosen which of those variables you want, type a / afterwards, then press TAB.

Comment: That shows completions the `*Completions*` buffer but the minubuffer continues to show `$envvar` as I entered it. I want to expand in the minubuffer, similar to what `readline` does on `shell-expand-line (M-C-e)`

Comment: For me it is expanding when I hit TAB after the slash. Win7, Emacs 24.3.1, non-cygwin build of emacs .

Comment: My fingers too are telling me that is how to expand them but that's not the behavior I see :) I am using 24.31 cygwin build but I can't imagine how this can be cygwin specific.